# Really easy PYTHON sorting float

Tags: python, sorting

I have a.txt file
this file's form is like this

```
1.0
2.32
10e-30
1.333
45.333
```

and I want to sort this values.
So, my code is

```
f=open('a.txt','r')
k={}
for line in f:
 p=line.strip().split('\t')
 k=float(p[0])
 q=sorted(k)
 print q
```

but, it says

```
'float' object is not iterable
```

I have to compare those text values.

Comment: You can only sort lists. `k` is not a list, so you can't sort it.

Comment: So, How could I sort a.txt's float values?

Comment: Put them into a list, then sort that list.

Comment: 1). `k={}` creates an empty `dict`, not an empty `list`. 2). When you do `k=float(p[0])` you _replace_ the old `k` object with a new one, in this case a single `float` number. The number doesn't get inserted into the old `k` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = []
with open('a.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        l.append(float(i))

l.sort()
for i in l:
    print i
```

Or you can do these things use list comprehensions like this. Only one line and more simpler:

```
l = sorted(float(line) for line in open('a.txt'))
```

And if you don't need to save them in a list, you can just print them:

```
print sorted(float(line) for line in open('a.txt'))
```

**Thanks @TessellatingHeckler**.

Comment: Good start, but this will do a lexicographic sort, causing values like "10.5" to appear before "4.8", even though the former would be larger if they were both floats instead of strings.

Comment: @Kevin I think this can work now. convert these string to float, append to a list and sort them.

Comment: Getting better, but it's inefficient to sort the list every time you add a new item.

Comment: @Kevin What about now? :)

Comment: Since you aren't doing any error checking on the file, you can read it all into a list in one list comprehension `l = [line for line in open('a.txt')]`. And make them floats and be able to get the sorted answer `l = sorted(float(line) for line in open('a.txt'))` -- or forget building and saving a list, print it directly with `print(sorted(float(line) for line in open('a.txt')))`. List comprehensions are more idiomatic but could be `print(sorted(map(float, open('a.txt'))))`. (Not criticism of your answer, just riffing on it)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler These ideas are so good, I'll add them to my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

This will work provided each line of the file has only floating point nuumbers as shown in your example.

```
   with open('a.txt') as fin:
        text = fin.read().split()
        text = [float(k) for k in text]
        text.sort()
        print(text)
```

Comment: Actually, because `.split()` with no arg splits on one or more whitespace chars, your code will cope with a wide variety of data layouts. It'll handle multiple numbers on each line, as long as they're separated by one or more spaces or tabs.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say "If each line of the file has only floating point numbers."  I'll edit the answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.